# In the custom model, keras.layers.Embedding Output Shape is multiple

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to use keras.layers.Embedding in a customized sub-model. But output shape is 'multiple'.Then I try to write a demo and test it

The results of the two methods are different,and I'm not sure if it's my problem.

model1 return me a clear output shape

but model2 give me a 'multiple'

here is the full demo code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import numpy as np

myPath = "./data/"
embedding_matrix = np.load(myPath + "embeddings_matrix.npy",allow_pickle=True)

model1=keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.InputLayer(5),
    keras.layers.Embedding(len(embedding_matrix), 100,weights=[embedding_matrix],trainable=False,mask_zero=True,name="embedding_layer"),
    keras.layers.Dense(200)
],name="model1")

model1.build((None,5))
model1.summary()

class myModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self,
                 embedding_matrix,
                 embedding_out=100,
                 **kwargs):
        super(myModel, self).__init__(name='model2')

        self.input_x = keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=5)
        self.embedding_layer = keras.layers.Embedding(len(embedding_matrix), embedding_out,weights=[embedding_matrix],trainable=False,mask_zero=True,name="embedding",input_length=5)
        self.dense = keras.layers.Dense(200)

    def call(self,x):
        x = self.input_x(x)
        y = self.embedding_layer(x)
        y = self.dense(y)
        return y

model2 = myModel(embedding_matrix)
model2.build((None,5))
model2.summary()
```

Here is the model.summary() info:

```
Model: "model1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
embedding_layer (Embedding)  (None, 5, 100)            5000400
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 5, 200)            20200
=================================================================
Total params: 5,020,600
Trainable params: 20,200
Non-trainable params: 5,000,400
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "model2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 5)]               0
_________________________________________________________________
embedding (Embedding)        multiple                  5000400
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              multiple                  20200
=================================================================
Total params: 5,020,600
Trainable params: 20,200
Non-trainable params: 5,000,400
_________________________________________________________________
```

I want to know the right way to use a keras.layers.Embedding in a customized sub-model